# Problems accessing the Tomcat directory

Tags: macos, apache, bash, tomcat

I have problems accessing the Tomcat directory, `mkdir` says file exists but when I try to change directory is says no such file. Seems like a weird contradiction. Please help me with this.

```
Spoorthys-MacBook-Pro:Library spoorthy$ mkdir Tomcat
mkdir: Tomcat: File exists
Spoorthys-MacBook-Pro:Library spoorthy$ cd Tomcat
-bash: cd: Tomcat: No such file or directory
Spoorthys-MacBook-Pro:Library spoorthy$
```

Comment: What does `ls -la` show you? Is there perhaps something else named Tomcat?

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x    1 spoorthy  admin    31 15 Oct 15:00 Tomcat -> /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47

Comment: i tried searching for Tomcat directory on spotlight but unfortunately it does nt show anything

Comment: Looks like `Tomcat` is a link to  `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47` check whether target directory `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47` exists.. if not then `Tomcat` is a broken link

Comment: it does not exist , can you please let me know how do i rectify the problem with this broken link

Comment: If you just want to create a new directory named `Tomcat` then you can simply delete the broken link and create the directory by using this command `rm -rf Tomcat; mkdir Tomcat`  but I am not sure how to get `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47` back. if you want to point Tomcat to any other directory then see mcoolive's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, RBH gave you the right answer: Tomcat is a broken link. That's why you read these error messages that seam in contradiction.

You can remove the broken link and create a new one:

```
rm -f Tomcat
ln -s <newPath> Tomcat
```